# contains function not calling the equals method to compare objects

Tags: java, hibernate, set, equals, gethashcode

I am using SQL query to get the Person object. This Person object has a set of interests which also I am getting from SQL query.

Now when I try to check if a interest object is contained in this Person Object, then it is not calling the equals method to check it.

Following is my code

```
class Interest {


private Person person ;

private Admin admin ;

//getter setters for Person and admin 
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (!(arg0 instanceof Interest)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this==arg0){
            return true;
        }

        if(this.person.equals(((Interest)arg0).getPerson()) && this.admin.equals(((Interest)arg0).getAdmin()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int hc=0;

        if(this.person !=null)
            hc= hc + 19 * this.person.getName().length();

        if(this.admin !=null)
            hc= hc + 19 * this.admin.getName().length();

        return hc;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String objStr = ((Interest)arg0).person.getName().toUpperCase();
    int value =  this.person.getName().toUpperCase().compareTo(objStr);

    return value;
}

}
```

Now in the person class I am having code as follows :

```
class Person {

private Set interest ;


//other fields 

//getter and setters 

public boolean isInterestExists(Interest interest){

return this.interest.contains(interest);
}

}
```

Now I am executing this from

```
person.isInterestExists(interest);
```

It is not calling the equals method of Interest class. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is it calling `hashCode`?

Comment: No Sir, it is not calling hashcode also . It is only going in  the compareTo function .

Comment: Then your Set is probably a TreeSet, not a HashSet. That's how TreeSet work. Java 5 came out more than 10 years ago. Why aren't you using generic types yet? And why don't you indent your code?

Comment: Yes Sir, the set is TreeSet . Sorry forgot to mention that. Sir, when I use hql  to take out the full objects of Person and then I do contains then it goes to equals and hashCode. Only when I am using sql it is not going to equals and hashCode method .

Comment: HQL is completely irrelevant. A HashSet uses equals and hashCode to compare objects. A TreeSet uses compareTo. Where the objects come from is irrelevant. Those two methods should be equivalent, i.e. a.equals(b) iff a.compareTo(b) == 0. Not respecting this rule is begging for problems.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your help .